# Make check box like button and clickable

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I've created a checkbox and made it look like a button. I'm facing an issue with this checkbox, its not clickable anywhere on the box. It only activates when click exactly on text. Is it possible to activate the checkbox by clicking anywhere on the button?

```css
.nft-item-category-list input[type=checkbox]+label {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0.2em 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0.2em 0;
  text-align: left;
  font: normal normal normal 14px/14px Poppins;
  color: #8E8E93;
}

.nft-item-category-list input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}

.nft-item-category-list input[type=checkbox]+label:before {
  content: "✓";
  display: none;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  padding-left: 0.1em;
  padding-bottom: 0.10em;
  margin-right: 0.5em;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  color: transparent;
  transition: .2s;
  color: #000;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: #8E8E93;
}

.nft-item-category-list input[type=checkbox]+label:active:before {
  transform: scale(0);
  color: #000;
}

.nft-item-category-list input[type=checkbox]:checked+label:before {
  background-color: MediumSeaGreen;
  border-color: MediumSeaGreen;
  color: #000;
}

.nft-item-category-list input[type=checkbox]:disabled+label:before {
  transform: scale(1);
  border-color: #aaa;
}

.nft-item-category-list input[type=checkbox]:checked:disabled+label:before {
  transform: scale(1);
  background-color: #bfb;
  border-color: #bfb;
}

.nft-item-category-list input[type=checkbox]:checked+label {
  color: #30D158;
  transition: all .2s linear;
}

ul.nft-item-categories {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  gap: 15px;
  align-items: center;
}

li.nft-item-category-list {
  background: #2C2C2E 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 184px;
  height: 41px;
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nft-item-categories">
  <li class="nft-item-category-list">
    <input type="checkbox" id="cat1" name="cat1" value="Business">
    <label for="cat1">Business</label>
  </li>
  <li class="nft-item-category-list">
    <input type="checkbox" id="cat2" name="cat2" value="Animals">
    <label for="cat2">Animals</label>
  </li>
  <li class="nft-item-category-list">
    <input type="checkbox" id="cat3" name="cat3" value="Technology">
    <label for="cat3">Technology</label>
  </li>
  <li class="nft-item-category-list">
    <input type="checkbox" id="cat4" name="cat4" value="Industry">
    <label for="cat4">Industry</label>
  </li>
  <li class="nft-item-category-list">
    <input type="checkbox" id="cat5" name="cat5" value="Food">
    <label for="cat5">Food</label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: When you use labels, you are basically saying that this new thing is equal to the old thing. you are equaling a text( like Food, Industry, ...) to a checkbox. So it is expected to act like this. Instead of styling your `li`, put a wrapper div aroung each of your texts, and style them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since label is only element that can trigger input, therefor instead of `li` apply button style to `label`
so it will look and act like button.
`li.nft-item-category-list label`

```css
.nft-item-category-list input[type=checkbox]+label {
  margin: 0.2em 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0.2em 0;
  text-align: left;
  font: normal normal normal 14px/14px Poppins;
  color: #8E8E93;
}

.nft-item-category-list input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}

.nft-item-category-list input[type=checkbox]+label:before {
  content: "✓";
  display: none;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  padding-left: 0.1em;
  padding-bottom: 0.10em;
  margin-right: 0.5em;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  color: transparent;
  transition: .2s;
  color: #000;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: #8E8E93;
}

.nft-item-category-list input[type=checkbox]+label:active:before {
  transform: scale(0);
  color: #000;
}

.nft-item-category-list input[type=checkbox]:checked+label:before {
  background-color: MediumSeaGreen;
  border-color: MediumSeaGreen;
  color: #000;
}

.nft-item-category-list input[type=checkbox]:disabled+label:before {
  transform: scale(1);
  border-color: #aaa;
}

.nft-item-category-list input[type=checkbox]:checked:disabled+label:before {
  transform: scale(1);
  background-color: #bfb;
  border-color: #bfb;
}

.nft-item-category-list input[type=checkbox]:checked+label {
  color: #30D158;
  transition: all .2s linear;
}

ul.nft-item-categories {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  gap: 15px;
  align-items: center;
}

li.nft-item-category-list label{
  background: #2C2C2E 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 184px;
  height: 41px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}


li.nft-item-category-list{
list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nft-item-categories">
  <li class="nft-item-category-list">
    <input type="checkbox" id="cat1" name="cat1" value="Business">
    <label for="cat1">Business</label>
  </li>
  <li class="nft-item-category-list">
    <input type="checkbox" id="cat2" name="cat2" value="Animals">
    <label for="cat2">Animals</label>
  </li>
  <li class="nft-item-category-list">
    <input type="checkbox" id="cat3" name="cat3" value="Technology">
    <label for="cat3">Technology</label>
  </li>
  <li class="nft-item-category-list">
    <input type="checkbox" id="cat4" name="cat4" value="Industry">
    <label for="cat4">Industry</label>
  </li>
  <li class="nft-item-category-list">
    <input type="checkbox" id="cat5" name="cat5" value="Food">
    <label for="cat5">Food</label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @LeeTaylor I just gave him the answer/solution rest he can fix it by his own.

Comment: @LeeTaylor Updated the code, hoping you agree with it now :)

Answer (score 2):

I would just move your li styles to your label:

```css
.nft-item-category-list input[type=checkbox]+label {
  cursor: pointer;
  font: normal normal normal 14px/14px Poppins;
  color: #8E8E93;
  background: #2C2C2E;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 184px;
  height: 41px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.nft-item-category-list input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}

.nft-item-category-list input[type=checkbox]+label:before {
  content: "✓";
  display: none;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  padding-left: 0.1em;
  padding-bottom: 0.10em;
  margin-right: 0.5em;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  color: transparent;
  transition: .2s;
  color: #000;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: #8E8E93;
}

.nft-item-category-list input[type=checkbox]+label:active:before {
  transform: scale(0);
  color: #000;
}

.nft-item-category-list input[type=checkbox]:checked+label:before {
  background-color: MediumSeaGreen;
  border-color: MediumSeaGreen;
  color: #000;
}

.nft-item-category-list input[type=checkbox]:disabled+label:before {
  transform: scale(1);
  border-color: #aaa;
}

.nft-item-category-list input[type=checkbox]:checked:disabled+label:before {
  transform: scale(1);
  background-color: #bfb;
  border-color: #bfb;
}

.nft-item-category-list input[type=checkbox]:checked+label {
  color: #30D158;
  transition: all .2s linear;
}

ul.nft-item-categories {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  gap: 15px;
  align-items: center;
}

li.nft-item-category-list {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nft-item-categories">
  <li class="nft-item-category-list">
    <input type="checkbox" id="cat1" name="cat1" value="Business">
    <label for="cat1">Business</label>
  </li>
  <li class="nft-item-category-list">
    <input type="checkbox" id="cat2" name="cat2" value="Animals">
    <label for="cat2">Animals</label>
  </li>
  <li class="nft-item-category-list">
    <input type="checkbox" id="cat3" name="cat3" value="Technology">
    <label for="cat3">Technology</label>
  </li>
  <li class="nft-item-category-list">
    <input type="checkbox" id="cat4" name="cat4" value="Industry">
    <label for="cat4">Industry</label>
  </li>
  <li class="nft-item-category-list">
    <input type="checkbox" id="cat5" name="cat5" value="Food">
    <label for="cat5">Food</label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

set your label to 'display:block';  ...width and height should be the same as the li, set text-align:center, and line-height same as height and you're good to go

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).